# How do you add a statically created Qt Module to a project without setting the source as a subproject?

Tags: qt, cmake, qml

Everywhere I look, the only examples for using a statically created qml module to a Qt project involve having the library source as a child of the project that will use it.
[Such as here in the Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-writing-a-module.html)

How do you link a statically built external plugin?
To simplify the question, what steps are necessary to use `TestP` in this situation?

- Create a new Qt6 app `TestApp` in QtCreator (v10 here)
- Create a new Quick2ExtensionPlugin `TestP` in QtCreator

  - This generates a QML file `MyItemControls.qml` and a C++ class `MyItem`
- Add `MyItemControls {}` and `MyItem {}` to TestApp's `Main.qml`

---

So far the best I have been able to do is to use MyItem (c++). MyItemControls (qml) throws a `qrc:/TestP/MyItemControls.qml: no such file or directory` error.

- Build TestP
- Copy TestP.lib and the TestP folder somewhere
- TestP folder contains TestPplugin.lib, MyItemControls.qml and the necessary qmldir, etc files
- Link to TestP.lib and TestPplugin.lib in TestApp's CMakeLists
- Add a call to `Q_IMPORT_QML_PLUGIN(TestPPlugin)` in main.cpp
- Add MyItemControls and/or MyItem to TestApp's main.qml and then Build
- My Item works, MyItemControls throws a `MyItemControls is not an item` error
- `set(QT_QML_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/qml")` and copy TestP/ to ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/qml/TestP

  - MyItemControls throws a `qrc:/TestP/MyItemControls.qml: no such file or directory` error

---

I've confirmed that with the above steps TestP isn't being added to `qrc:/`

The only thing I can see that's different from other examples is the lack of 'add_subdirectory' (like in this [Scythe Studios example](https://github.com/scytheStudio/qt_add_qml_module_example/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt), but I'm trying to do this without access to the source code.

Comment: Do you specify your QML file in the qt_add_qml_module call in the module CMake file? Do you have your module in the call to target_link_libraries in the main CMake file?

Comment: Would be easier if you provide your CMake files...

Comment: @JürgenLutz There is too much code to paste everything, but I gave the steps to reproduce my environment exactly, if you're interested in trying.
"Link TestP.lib and TestPplugin.lib in TestApp's CMakeLists". 

`target_link_library(${project} path/to/TestP.lib path/to/TestPplugin.lib)`

Comment: (That's why I can use MyItem, the cpp QObject)

Comment: "Do you specify your QML file in the qt_add_qml_module call in the module CMake file?" Yes. It's the Quick2 Extension Plugin template, so MyItemControls.qml is added to the plugin. It's listed in the qmldir file as well

Answer (score 0):

Sort of an answer.

Linking to the TestPplugin.lib is not the same as linking to the CMake target TestPplugin. Something `qt_add_qml_plugin` (called by `qt_add_qml_module`) is doing some other magic in the cmake build process that isn't propagated to the .lib. Apparently this is a known issue (since at least 2023/01) currently without a solution.